# Let vs. var in a for loop

Tags: javascript, closures

Like was previously said here: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

The output for this code is always `3`

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // let's create 3 functions
  funcs[i] = function() {          // and store them in funcs
    console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
  };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();                      // and now let's run each one to see
}
// My value: 3
// My value: 3
// My value: 3
```

This happens is because there's no difference between the global `i` and the `i` inside the anonymous function of the loop. So that when `funcs[i]` gets called, its current value is already `3`.

The classic way to solve this is via a closure.

```
var funcs = [];

function createfunc(i) {
    return function() { console.log("My value: " + i); };
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    funcs[i] = createfunc(i);
}

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j]();                        // and now let's run each one to see
}
```

By wrapping the function creation in the `createfunc(i)` function, you ensure that the value of "i" is bound to an unchanging value outside the function.

One way to solve this and that I don't get is through the creation of a `let` variable.

```
 var funcs = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      
      funcs[i] = function() {          
        console.log("My value: " + i);
      };
    }

funcs[0]();
funcs[1]();
funcs[2]();
funcs[3]();
```

By doing so, I'd expect the variable `let` to be **only** accessible inside the loop, hence at the time I'm calling the function `i` is still `undefined`.

Since it works, it looks like JS is able to assign the proper variable `i` while still in the for loop and at the time I invoke the function it has the proper value `i` assigned.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just an aside, your "closure creation" can be an IIFE. `funcs[i] = (function(i) {return function() {console.log(i);};})(i);` - obviously with spacing for readability :D

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol true. Nice one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

The function is defined inside the loop, so it has access to all the variables that exist inside the loop, and it closes over them and continues to have access to them so long as the function exists.

Comment: What you are saying is that the anonymous function is a closure and so it carries all the variables that were created in the environment where the function has been declared and since it was declared in the for loop it carries the value of "i". Correct?