# Async ordered queue executer in js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, queue

I have NodeJS app where I connect WS server, listen for new messages -
and on each message I do aysnc job.

The problem:
the jobs takes time - and I want to run them one at a time and in the order they received.

eg:
message1 -> job(message) // 1000ms
message2 -> job2(message2) // 5000ms
messgae3 -> (received before job2 done but executed only after job2 done) -> job2(message3)

So I made this classes to simulate the beavior of the NodeJS app, and still in this code the jobs doesn't run ordered and it looks like it doesn't wait for previous one to finish (not sure)

```js
class AsyncQueue {
    constructor() {
        this.active = false
        this.queue = []
    }

    async doJobs() {
        if (this.active) {
            return
        }

        this.active = true
        while (this.queue.length > 0) {
            const fn = this.queue.shift() // take first
            await fn()
        }
        this.active = false
    }

    push(fn) {
        this.queue.push(fn) // push to last
        this.doJobs()
    }
}

class Utils {
    static randInt(min, max) {
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min
    } 
    
    static sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
    }
}


class WsServer {
    static async onMessage(func) {
        while (true) {
            await Utils.sleep(1000)
            func()
        }
    }
}


async function job(name) {
    console.log(`Doing job ${name}`)
    await Utils.sleep(Utils.randInt(1000, 5000)) // Fake job takes time
    console.log(`Done doing job ${name}`)
}

async function main() {
    const queue = new AsyncQueue()
    let counter = 0
    WsServer.onMessage(() => {
        counter += 1;
        queue.push(() => job(counter))
    })
}

main()
```

Comment: I tried that but still it runs the jobs out of sync

Comment: It seems like the closure is your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923825/let-vs-var-in-a-for-loop The counter is incremented and the function uses the incremented value, not the value the counter had at the time the function was pushed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions are already processed in order. The counter confuses you. The confusing behavior of the counter is caused by the closure as described in [Let vs. var in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923825/let-vs-var-in-a-for-loop)

The function is pushed into the queue and has access to the counter through the closure. The counter is incremented after the function is pushed and the function prints the incremented counter. You can see it with this code:

```js
class AsyncQueue {
    constructor() {
        this.active = false
        this.queue = []
    }

    async doJobs() {
        if (this.active) {
            return
        }

        this.active = true
        while (this.queue.length > 0) {
            const fn = this.queue.shift() // take first
            await fn()
        }
        this.active = false
    }

    push(fn) {
        this.queue.push(fn) // push to last
        this.doJobs()
    }
}

class Utils {
    static randInt(min, max) {
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min
    } 
    
    static sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
    }
}


class WsServer {
    static async onMessage(func) {
        while (true) {
            await Utils.sleep(1000)
            func()
        }
    }
}


async function job(name) {
    console.log(`Doing job ${name}`)
    await Utils.sleep(Utils.randInt(1000, 5000)) // Fake job takes time
    console.log(`Done doing job ${name}`)
}

async function main() {
    const queue = new AsyncQueue()
    let counter = 0
    WsServer.onMessage(() => {
        counter += 1;
        queue.push(((counter) => () => job(counter))(counter))
    })
}

main()
```

I didn't change anything in the processing of the functions. I only changed how the function accesses the counter.

A simple version of the problem:

```js
const list = [];

let i = 0;
list.push(() => console.log(i));
++i;
list.push(() => console.log(i));
++i;
list.push(() => console.log(i));
++i;
list.push(() => console.log(i));

list.forEach(f => f());
```

and the simple solution:

```js
const list = [];

let i = 0;
list.push(((i) => () => console.log(i))(i));
++i;
list.push(((i) => () => console.log(i))(i));
++i;
list.push(((i) => () => console.log(i))(i));
++i;
list.push(((i) => () => console.log(i))(i));

list.forEach(f => f());
```

IMO it's not an duplicate, because it's unrelated to loops and it can't be solved using `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: you could `queue.push(((v) => () => job(v))(counter));` instead, then no need to change any other code at all :p

Comment: @JaromandaX The additional array was for me. I needed it to debug and understand the problem. It could be useful if the OP also wants to play with and debug it.

Comment: fair enough ... there's also even easier `const v = ++counter; queue.push(() => job(v));` in `.onMessage`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, the common solution is to pass the value as argument to a function. How you do it, is your choice. I think, it doesn't matter in this case, because the OP used it to prove a problem that doesn't exist. The functions are processed in order. The OP used the counter for debugging. If the OP wants to fix this behavior, I've found dozens of duplicates / similar questions.